Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$ be a invertible block matrix. Is it true that either $A$ or $C$ is invertible?
I know that if $X=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$ is positive and invertible, then the diagonal entries have to be strictly positive also. But what about the case when $X$ is not positive? Certainly, in that case, it is not true. For instance, $A=D=0$ and $B=C=I$. My guess is in general case, either $A$ or $C$ has to be invertible at least. But I am not able to establish this.
Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

It is false. Try a permutation of the rows of the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix. Just switch the middle two rows.

What exactly is the question? If $A=D=0$, $B=C=I$, then $X$ is invertible, so exactly which claim was that supposed to refute?

Your title says $X$ is invertible, but the body specifically asks for non-invertible. Edit the title.

Sorry, there is a mistake in the body. the second sentence of the body would be "X is not positive".

@DeltaEpsilon Positive of X, means elementwise or positve definite?

Consider $$X=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}. $$
